# Workaround for goto

Tags: php, goto

I came to situation when I need to check if array2 has some value (randomly generated) from array1. So far I though of

```
redo : $id=mt_rand(0,count(array1));
foreach($array2 as $arr)
{
    if($arr[0]==$id) goto redo;
}
//Some actions if randomly generated value from array1 wasn't found in array2
```

But I'd really prefer not to use goto. I'm pretty sure there is some simple solution to do this without goto but I just can't think of it D:

Comment: `do { $id = mt_rand(...); $contains = /* determine if the array contains this id */; } while ($contains);`

Comment: Use a proper structure (`do-while`) as suggested, and remember...
**Never never never** and **NEVER** use `goto` operator. It's a joke. For real: look at the [comic](http://it.php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png) at the bottom of the [PHP manual](http://it.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a numeric parameter with `continue`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

```
while(true){
  $id = mt_rand(0,count(array1);

  foreach( $array2 as $arr )
    // restart the outer while loop if $id found
    if( $arr[0] == $id ) continue 2;

  // $id not found in array, leave the while loop ...
  break;
};

// ... and do the action
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$flag=true;
 do{
      $id=mt_rand(0,count(array1);

      foreach( $array2 as $arr )
        if( $arr[0] == $id ) break;

      // do it and set flag to false when you need to exit;

    } while($flag);
```

Comment: if just set $flag=false after foreach, do-while loop will end in both cases (if there was match and if there wasn't). Then there is need for an additional flag before break which will be check after foreach loop to see if there was match. This is hassle so code by biziclop works way better here